# need to rewrite for a mobile controller in Kohana

Tags: .htaccess, kohana, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite in htaccess

`mobile.domain.com/mobile/function` into `mobile.domain.com/function`

I thought the below would work but it thinks that the function is a controller.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]

# Rewrite for Mobile
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}    ^mobile\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}  !mobile [NC]
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          /mobile/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try swapping

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

with

```
# Rewrite for Mobile
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}    ^mobile\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}  !mobile [NC]
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          /mobile/$1 [L]
```

---

EDIT:

Okay, try this instead of what you currently have:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]

# Rewrite for Mobile
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}    ^mobile\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}  !mobile [NC]
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     ^(\w+)$          /mobile/$1


# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```